# splitting string into float numbers in python

Tags: python-2.7

I would like to split string in following format

'1 3.04900E+03 -9.04741E+02 2.50000E+03 4.00000E+01 -6.77627E+01    2.00095E+03 -1.49179E+02    3.04900E+03 2.00000E+01 6.80000E+01 -4.80000E+01    1.35648E+05 '

into seperate float numbers, how should i do that? Thank you in advance!

Inge

Comment: Please share any code you have written with an attempt to solve this problem. What specific aspects of accomplishing this are you having difficulties with?

Answer (score 2):

You can use .split(delimiter) to split a string using `delimiter` as the item to split on. In your case this looks like a single space `' '`. Therefore the following would give you a list of numbers. The list comprehension generates a float for each value in the string and stores them in a list

```
>>> my_string='1 3.04900E+03 -9.04741E+02 2.50000E+03 4.00000E+01 -6.77627E+01 2.00095E+03 -1.49179E+02 3.04900E+03 2.00000E+01 6.80000E+01 -4.80000E+01 1.35648E+05'
>>> my_float_list= [float(x) for x in my_string.split(' ')]
>>> print my_float_list
[1.0, 3049.0, -904.741, 2500.0, 40.0, -67.7627, 2000.95, -149.179, 3049.0, 20.0, 68.0, -48.0, 135648.0]
```